# Update action with empty password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

In Michael Hartl's tutorial, the following is stated.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :remember_token
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

end
```

In case you’re worried that Listing 9.10 might allow new users to sign up with empty passwords, recall from Section 6.3.3 that has_secure_password includes a separate presence validation that specifically catches nil passwords.

My question is, how is the has_secure_password validation working if it allows the test to pass? I do not understand, clearly the has_secure_password validation is not "catching" this rule to bypass an empty password.

Further, how does rails know not to set and save the empty passwords to the user? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password) , it explains everything in details,

According to the source code:

```
def has_secure_password
   .....
   if options.fetch(:validations, true)
     include ActiveModel::Validations

   # This ensures the model has a password by checking whether the password_digest
   # is present, so that this works with both new and existing records. However,
   # when there is an error, the message is added to the password attribute instead
   # so that the error message will make sense to the end-user.
     validate do |record|
       record.errors.add(:password, :blank) unless record.password_digest.present?
     end

     validates_length_of :password, maximum: ActiveModel::SecurePassword::MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH_ALLOWED
     validates_confirmation_of :password, allow_blank: true
   end
   ..........
end
```

if you did not call `has_secure_password(validations: false)` the three types of validations will be added. i think the reason of the passing test is :

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
```

> The `:allow_nil` option skips the validation when the value being
>   validated is nil.

**To Add**

> how does rails know not to set and save the empty passwords to the
>   user?

I think it's because the `params[:user][:password]` is blank and not nil